# what is meaning behind this statement int i = x & y in C#?

Tags: c#, .net

I'm not sure what is meaning of this statement:

```
int i = x & y;
```

I ran this example

```
int x = 1 & 2;
int y = 5;
int sum = x + y;
```

***result is 5*** and I'm not sure that I get idea of what **`&`** operator does in this case

Comment: Refer this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/boolean-logical-operators#logical-and-operator-

Comment: `&` is bitwise AND

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `&` operator is a **bitwise AND**. To see what it does, you look at the bit patterns.

So if `1` has this binary bit pattern:

```
0 1
```

And `2` has this binary bit pattern:

```
1 0
```

you put them together and look at the columns:

```
0 1
1 0
```

Only keep `1` values for columns where ALL of the values are `1`. So we have this result:

```
0 0
```

Which is `0`.

Therefore after the first line of code, `x` has a value of `0`, and `0` plus `5` is still `5`.

---

For another example, let's do this expression: `1 & 3`. We have these two binary bit patterns:

```
0 1
1 1
```

Which produces this result:

```
0 1
```

So we get `1`. We can also do `2 & 3`:

```
1 0
1 1
```

To get this result:

```
1 0
```

Which is `2`.

---

The bitwise AND has a number of uses. One of the simple ones is checking for even vs odd. The expression `x & 1 == 1` is a quick way to check if a variable `x` is odd. `x & 1 == 0` is quick check whether it's even.

Answer (score 2):

**&** is the bit-wise operator in C#

therefore, int x = 1 & 2 would give 0 as the result. This is because 1 in binary can be represented as *01* and 2 as *10*. The AND operation between the two would thus result in *00* i.e. 0

With the value of x being 0 and y being 5, the result for their sum comes out to be 5

For more info on bitwise operators, please refer [MS docs | Logical AND operator &](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/bitwise-and-shift-operators#logical-and-operator-)